# Create multiple spreadsheets with varying names

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to create multiple worksheets worksheet names based on the values in a specific cell specific worksheet in the same workbook.

Then copy values from another worksheet to the created worksheet.

I know how to loop through a set of varying values so that is not the issue.  Below is to create one specific spreadsheet based on the value in a cell.

I am having a problem converting the name of the new spreadsheet variable to use in my pasting statement.

Cell `sheets("Input").Range("H2")` stores a formula with the sheet name to be created
`Sheets("Forms").Range("PrintRng")` is from a source worksheet with the formatted formula and text values to copied into the new worksheet

Please review the attached VBA and suggest a solution.

```
Sub AddNewSheetswithNameExample2()

Sheets.Add.Name = Sheets("Input").Range("H2")
Dim wsName As Variant
Set wsName = Sheets("Input").Range("H2")
Sheets("Form").Range("PrintRng").Copy.Values
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("wsName").Range("A1:M36").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You never use a variables name together with quotation marks.

So the correct way to use it, would be `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(wsName)` (instead of ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(**"**wsName**"**))

But your code could be enhanced:

```vb
Sub AddNewSheetswithNameExample()

dim wsName as String
wsName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input").Range("H2").value

Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
wsTarget.Name = wsName

Dim rgSource As Range
Set rgSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Form").Range("PrintRng")

With rgSource
    wsTarget.Range("A1").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
End With

End Sub
```